# Prove $ \sum^{n}_{j=1}f(j)(n-j)!=n!$ and $ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f(n)x^n=1-{1\over F(x)} $

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A homework from my Combinatorics course has the following excersise:

> A permutation $ a_{1} $... $a_n$ of $[n]$ is called indecomposable or connected
> if n is the least positive integer j for which $ \{{a_1, a_2, ..., a_j }\}=\{{1, 2,..., j }\} $. Let $f(n)$ be the number of indecomposable permutations of
> $[n]$, and set $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n!x^n, n≥0 $. Show that:
>
> 1. $ \sum^{n}_{j=1}f(j)(n-j)!=n! $
> 2. $ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f(n)x^n=1-{1\over F(x)} $

I have read the whole chapter which includes this topic in *Enumerative Combinatorics* by R.P. Stanley and also some posts about *Connected permutation graphs* and could not find a single idea or concept that would help me solve this excersise. All I could deduce is that the first problem is somewhat an answer to the second one. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your definition of indecomposable is very hard to follow, can you double-check it? Also, as a hint I think it may be helpful to think about permutations of $[n]$ where the first $k$ entries form an indecomposable permutation of $[k].$

Comment: This is a copy-paste from the Enumerative Combinatorics book it is in (ex. 128a) ... It is indecomposable to me too.. That excersise includes only the second equation but the "solution" to it has the first equation as a key point (and is not mentioned anywhere else)

Comment: Ok, well I did find [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427280/indecomposable-permutations) which refers to "indecomposable permutations," can you take a look and see if you think they mean the same thing? If so, I think an important thing to note is that all "decomposable" permutations can be split into an indecomposable part at the beginning followed by a permutation of the remaining numbers.

Comment: I noticed some mistakes I made in the post (first time writing in latex) so now it should be more readable. As of the post you linked, it still does not make any sense to me how that sum is connected to n!

Comment: I was really only linking it to see if we could solidify the idea of "indecomposable": with the edited definition it's a bit clearer so you can disregard that now if you'd like. My idea in terms of solving it is to consider that for each permutation of $[n],$ there will always be some prefix of it (maybe the whole thing) which is indecomposable. Suppose the largest such prefix is the first $j$ digits: now do you see how to proceed?

Comment: I see how the first part of j elements make yo that first part of equation, what I don't understand is how the sum end up being n! And also, how is the f(n) obtained? I have found tables of theose numbers but not how they are made

Comment: I realized I made a slight error before: we actually want the *smallest* such prefix. In any case, at this point it's probably best for me to just post an answer: writing that now. Regarding how $f(n)$ is obtained, I'm not entirely sure, if you've found tables but no explicit formula then it might just be that the best way is to brute-force it with a computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S(n)$ be the set of permutations of the numbers $1$ to $n.$ Trivially, we have

$$|S(n)| = n!$$

For any $a \in S(n),$ consider the function $d(a) = \min \{j \in \mathbb Z^+ : \{a_k : 1 \leq k \leq j\} = \{k: 1 \leq k \leq j\}\}.$ Note that because the output is a positive integer we must have $d(a) \geq 1,$ and because $a$ must contain the numbers from $1$ to $n$ we must have that $d(a) \leq n.$ (Edit: this also importantly guarantees that $d(a)$ is defined for all $a \in S(n)$)

Now consider the sets $S_k(n) = \{a \in S(n) : d(a) = k\}.$ Because we know that $1 \leq d(a) \leq n,$ we must have that

$$S(n) = \bigcup_{k = 1}^n S_k(n)$$

and because $d$ is a function, we must have that the $S_k$ sets are disjoint: otherwise, for some $k_1 \neq k_2$ such that there was some $p \in S_{k_1}(n)$ and $p \in S_{k_2}(n),$ then we would require both $d(p) = k_1$ and $d(p) = k_2,$ which would be a contradiction. So,

$$k_1 \neq k_2 \to S_{k_1}(n) \cap S_{k_2}(n) = \emptyset$$

Now note that saying that $d(a) = k$ is equivalent to saying that $a_1 \cdots a_k$ is an indecomposable permutation of the integers from $1$ to $k$: the definitions mean exactly the same thing. So, the set $S_k(n)$ is exactly the members of $S(n)$ which begin with an indecomposable permutation of the integers $1$ to $k,$ followed by any permutation of the integers $k + 1$ to $n.$ By definition we know that there are $f(k)$ indecomposable permutations, and for each of these there are $(n - (k+1) + 1)! = (n - k)!$ possible ways to end the permutation, so we have that

$$|S_k(n)| = f(k)(n - k)!$$

Now, because the $S_k(n)$ sets cover each member of $S(n)$ exactly once, we can conclude that

$$|S(n)| = \sum_{k = 1}^n |S_k(n)| = \sum_{k = 1}^n f(k)(n - k)!$$

and therefore

$$\boxed{\sum_{k = 1}^n f(k)(n - k)! = n!}$$

---

Edit: regarding the second part, we can prove this by multiplying the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty f(n)x^n$ with the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n!x^n$ using the Cauchy product formula for infinite series. Because the formula is typically written for sums starting at index $0,$ we'll reindex our first series to match:

$$\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} f(k+1)x^{k+1}\right)\left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n! x^n\right) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \sum_{j = 0}^i (f(j + 1)x^{j + 1})((i - j)!x^{i - j})$$

If you're unfamiliar with this process, the concept is that for any pair of indices $k$ and $n$ in our original sums, the summand will represent the product of those terms when $i = k + n$ and $j = k,$ and similarly any term in the sum with any given $i$ and $j$ will correspond with the product of the terms with $k = j$ and $n = i - j,$ so all combinations of terms are accounted for and there are no extras. Continuing by combining the powers and pulling them out to the front:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^\infty \left[x^{i+1} \sum_{j=0}^i f(j+1)(i-j)!\right]$$

Here if we could replace the $j+1$ with $j$ we would get $f(j)$ like we want, but then we would have $(i - j + 1)!$ so we also have to adjust $i.$ So, let $i' = i+1, j' = j+1$:

$$\sum_{i'-1 = 0}^\infty \left[x^{i'} \sum_{j'-1 = 0}^{i'-1} f(j')((i'-1)-(j'-1))!\right] = \sum_{i' = 1}^\infty \left[x^{i'} \sum_{j' = 1}^{i'} f(j')(i' - j')!\right]$$

Now we can simplify the inner sum using our identity:

$$\sum_{i' = 1}^\infty x^{i'}(i'!) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n!x^n - 1 = F(x) - 1$$

where the $-1$ accounts for the missing $n = 0$ term.

So, whenever $F(x)$ is not zero we have that:

$$F(x)\sum_{k = 1}^\infty f(k)x^k = F(x) - 1 \Rightarrow \boxed{\sum_{k = 1}^\infty f(k)x^k = 1 - \frac1{F(x)}}$$

Comment: Wow, now that it is presented this way, it seems pretty simple. Thank you! Still, this all somehow ties into the second equation and I don't see the connection.

Comment: We can prove the second equation by multiplying the two series in question together using the Cauchy product formula. It's a bit tricky, I can type that up as well if you'd like

Comment: If it's not too hard, please

Comment: @Traffy Should be ready to go